# How to capture link page loads in a WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I want to apply custom JS code when webpage loads in Android's `WebView`. I have a `WebView` with custom `WebViewClient`, overriding `onPageFinished()` and I apply the JS code there using

```
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { ... });");
```

which works nicely. However, there are some pages where upon clicking the link, the page is loaded "dynamically" (Using AJAX?) and the `onPageFinished()` is not called so our custom JS code is not applied.

An example of such a page is [https://reddit.com/r/Nature](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nature) (you need to use Chrome developer tools and set the mobile view), where threads are loaded dynamically upon clicking them.

How can I detect those page loads?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the method **[`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))**:

> *Give the host application a chance to take control when a URL is about to be loaded in the current WebView. If a WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the URL. If a WebViewClient is provided, returning true causes the current WebView to abort loading the URL, while returning false causes the WebView to continue loading the URL as usual.*

It should be overriden *twice*, if you want that the `WebView` works on old and new versions of Android like follows:

```
WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient()
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N) @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
    {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Page loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Sadly, the `onPageFinished()` get's called only the first time (when [www.reddit.com/r/Nature](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nature) is loaded). But when I click on some thread, and the new page is opened, this function is not called again. Something specific is happening on Reddit pages, because on other websites when I click regular `a href` links, `onPageFinished()` is called when new page is loaded. But not on Reddit:(

Comment: @PrimožKralj, **you have to override** the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` like in my example. This method is especially for the case like in yours. Do you have done it? Only in this case the method `onPageFinished()` will be called when new page is loaded **after link clicking**.

Comment: Yes, I have overriden it two times, same as in your example.

Comment: @PrimožKralj, you wrote: _Something specific is happening on Reddit pages, because on other websites when I click regular `a href` links, `onPageFinished()` is called when new page is loaded_. Does it mean that on other websites it works now (after method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` overriding),  and without overriding from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` it did not work on other websites? Did you check it on other websites with and without overriding from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`?

Comment: On other websites it worked previously without overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. After overriding them, nothing has changed for those sites (it works with or without). But the problematic page is Reddit. This one I am not able to solve in any way:(

Comment: @PrimožKralj, I think you do something wrong. It seems to work overall with those links. Try to write `System.out.println("link was clicked");` in the first line from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` in both places. And then write me the result.